# Problem with RSA-encrypting a string in PHP and passing it to .NET service

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

I need to call a web service that requires a login url containing an RSA encrypted, base_64 encoded and url-encoded login data. I don't have a formal php training, but even for me it seems like an easy task, however when calling the service I get an 'Invalid Format' response. What am I doing wrong and is there another way to come up with the encrypted string? Code example below. Thank you for your help!

```
require 'rsa.php'; // Uses rsa.php from http://www.edsko.net/misc/ for encryption.

$message = '?id=112233&param1=hello&email=hello@world.net&name=Name';

$keyLength = '2048';
$exponent = '65537';
$modulus = '837366556729991345239927764652........';
$encryptedData = rsa_encrypt($message, $exponent, $modulus, $keyLength);
$data = urlencode(base64_encode($encryptedData));

$loginurl = 'http://www.somedomain.com/LoginWB.aspx?Id=9876&Data='.$data;
echo '<iframe src="'.$loginurl.'" width="570px" height="800px">';
echo '</iframe>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The encryption looks correct to me. Are you sure the server is not complaining about the '?' in the `$message`?

If you care about performance, you should use openssl extensions. The public key operations are very slow in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had the same thought about the '?' in the message, and tried to remove it, but still get the same error.
With openssl, it requires a certificate in "pem" format. Do you know of any way to convert a simple text key to the "pem" certificate?